# Power Query / Power BI - replacing null values with value from another column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have run into the following error despite "No syntax errors have been detected", I have arrived at an error:

Expression.Error: The name 'each_' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.

Here are the lines of code including the final one that is obviously the issue for some reason.
(I'm trying to replace the null value in the column "Date" to be replaced with the value in the column "PS Source File Name - Copy.1")

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "APS Source File Name - Copy", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"APS Source File Name - Copy.1", "APS Source File Name - Copy.2"}),
#"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"APS Source File Name - Copy.1", type date}, {"APS Source File Name - Copy.2", type text}}),
#"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Changed Type3",{"APS Source File Name", "APS Source File Name - Copy.2", "APS Source File Name - Copy.1", "Date"}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Reordered Columns1",null,each_({"APS Source File Name - Copy.1",Replacer.ReplaceValue},{"Date"}))

in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Reordered Columns1",null, each [#"APS Source File Name - Copy.1"],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Date"})`