# Power Query Replace null values with values from another column

Tags: powerquery, m

I am working with data imported from a pdf file.  There is an extra column in the Power Query import (Data.Column7), containing data that belongs in the adjacent columns on either side (Data.Column6 and Data.Column8).  Columns 6 and 8 have null values in the cells where the data was pushed into Column 7.  I would like to replace the null values in Columns 6 and 8 with the correct data from Column 7, leaving all other values Columns 6 and 8 as is.

After looking at the post here:
[Power Query / Power BI - replacing null values with value from another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61056801/power-query-power-bi-replacing-null-values-with-value-from-another-column)

and watching this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikzeQgdKA0Q

I tried the following formula:

`= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded Data",null, each _[Data.Column7] ,Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Data.Column6","Data.Column8"})`

(Note, "Expanded Data" is the last step before this Replace Value step.)

I am not getting any kind of syntax error, but the Replace Value step isn't doing anything at all.  My null values in Columns 6 and 8 have not been replaced with the correct data from Column 7.

Any insight into how to achieve replacement would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

(I should mention, I am a new Power Query user, so please be detailed and assume I know nothing!)

Comment: Edit your question to include an example of your data that can be used to reproduce your problem.  In this case, both as text and also as a screenshot of the `Source` step from Power Query would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there must be some way to do this with the ReplaceValue function, but I think it might be easier to do the following:

1: Create a new column with definition NewData6= if[Data.Column6]=null then [Data.Column7] else [Data.Column6]
2: Do the same thing for 8 : NewData8= if[Data.Column8]=null then [Data.Column7] else [Data.Column8]
3: Delete Data.Column6/7/8
4: Rename the newly made columns if neccesary.

You can do these steps either in the advanced editor, or just use the create custom column button in the add column tab.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a solution for this, and I was able to do it as follows *(based on provided example)*:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded Data",null, each _[Data.Column7] ,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Data.Column6","Data.Column8"})
```

The difference then is the use of **Replacer.ReplaceValue** instead of **Replacer.ReplaceText**.

I noticed the *_* after each is not required.

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are of the text data type, then it might have empty strings instead of actual nulls.

Try replacing `null` with `""` in your formula.

Comment: No joy.  The null values didn't get replaced.